How to create a bivariate choropleth map with continuous variables in QGIS
I would like to display the values of two continuous (!) variables in a map in QGIS at the same time. I don't know the best way to do so, but the following image I found caught my eye (which apparently is called a bivariate choropleth)

I am now trying to replicate this in QGIS. All examples of doing so which I have found, however, make use of discrete variables, either through 3 or 4 categories per variable. This does not make sense with my data. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to figure out (through my own experimentation as well as through looking online) how to achieve this result.
So my question is twofold

Do you think this is the best way to display two continuous variables in a single map at the same time?
If so, how can I replicate this in QGIS?

I tried experimenting myself, as well as looking for other threads, here on stackoverflow as well as on the QGIS Reddit
